# How to define a relation symbol between `\prurel` and `\owns` in the boisik font?

Tags: symbols

First an MWS and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{boisik}

\begin{document}

\[
A\prurel B \text{ and } A\owns B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want is between `\prurel` and `\owns`: (1) the right side of the desired symbol is similar to `\prurel`, (2) the left side of the desired symbol is similar to `\owns`, and (3) the size of the desired symbol is the same as `\owns` or `\in`. Then how to define such a symbol? The following is a sketch.

[image]

Furthermore, if we have such a symbol, then how to flip it horizontally to get a new symbol, which is as `\in` to `\owns`?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that `boisik` fonts are only bitmap?

Comment: @egreg I just use it to show what I want clearly, so you could define such a symbol without boisik.

Comment: The desired symbol is not very clear for me. Maybe you can draw a sketch on paper or in a graphics editor and add that to the question? Also, is this a completely new symbol that you want to introduce or is it already used elsewhere? If it is new then the usual warning applies that it will be confusing for readers to encounter a new symbol and it is better to stick to the symbol conventions in your field.

Comment: @Marijn I upload a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the sketch, I leave to you to fine tune.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\varin}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\varin@\subset}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\varowns}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\varin@\supset}}

\newcommand{\varin@scale}[1]{\scalebox{0.7}[0.465]{#1}}
\newcommand{\varin@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \m@th
    \offinterlineskip
    \sbox\z@{$#1\mkern0.5mu$}%
    \ialign{##\cr\varin@scale{$#1\bm{#2}$}\cr\noalign{\kern-\wd\z@}\varin@scale{$#1\bm{#2}$}\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\varowns\owns\in\varin$

$A\varowns x \varin B \in C$

$\scriptstyle A\varowns x \varin B$

$\scriptscriptstyle A\varowns x \varin B$

\large
$A\varowns x \varin B$

\Large
$A\varowns x \varin B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks nice - is there a reason the symbol extends below the baseline (I guess that is a deliberate choice)?

Comment: As @Marjin said, could we improve the baseline and the size to be the same as `\in`?

Comment: @M.Logic Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks! Good symbol! By the way, could we draw it in TiKz or Picture2e to make it have the same line weight for everywhere?